# Python IF statements not running despite conditions met

Tags: python

In my code I have grabbed an integer from a text file and globally declared it as the variable 'accessLevel1', so it could be used to run validation checks in other areas of the code. However, despite the variable value being saved as '2' when using the first staff login details, an IF statement dependent on the variable being '2' is not running at all.

The contents of the text file titled 'staffDetails':

> *Jonas,Hills,JHills375,Sweirl900,2,
>
> Ellie,Glover,EGlover919,KHaisen10,1,*

Code used for grabbing the variable:

```
validateStaff = open("staffDetails.txt", "r")
    for row in validateStaff:\
        record = row.split(",")
        if record[2] == (entered_text):
            forename = record[0]
            surname = record[1]
            username = record[2]
            password = record[3]
            accessLevel = record[4]
            if record[3] == (entered_text2):
                global forename1
                global accessLevel1
                global surname1
                surname1 = surname
                forename1 = forename
                accessLevel1 = accessLevel
```

**The problem code**

```
def modclick(): #A function that occurs when a button is pressed
    print("Your access level is: " + (accessLevel1)) #This is here for demonstrative purposes of the problem
    if accessLevel1 == '1':
        errorLabelstock.config(fg='red') #this actually works somehow
        
    if accessLevel1 == '2':
        modifystock() #This function isn't called despite printing that the access level is 2

    if accessLevel1 == '3':
        modifystock()
```

**Proof that the system interpretted the variable 'accessLevel1' to be of the value 2 yet not executing the IF statement:**
[image]

Comment: What do you get with `print("Your access level is: |" + accessLevel1 + "|")`? This will show you if there's whitespace around the string, which you can't see in the current output (although I don't see why there would be, given your input file doesn't have it)

Comment: Are you sure the function isn't called? Could you be calling the wrong function or could the function be doing nothing? How about if you replace `modifystock()` with `print("Modifying stock")`?

Comment: "Your access level is: |2 
|". It takes a new line for the second 'I' though, not sure how to format that in a comment

Comment: Yes... Do `accessLevel = record[4].strip()`

Comment: Or use `csv.reader` which takes care of all this nonsense for you :)

Comment: Also yes I'm sure I'm calling the right function because I already ran print tests and it doesn't do anything, the IF statement just has no process or output seemingly

Comment: There you go! Your line ends with a newline character which is included with the last element of `split()`. Do what @OneCricket said. Better yet, `strip()` the line _before_ you split it. Even better, do what @Samwise said

Comment: @OneCricketeer or `row.rstrip().split(',')`

Comment: Just a tip, but if Python won't run your conditional code then the condition is definitely not met :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following line, this will fix it

```
accessLevel1 = str(accessLevel1).strip()
```

Comment: Yeah, adding the strip worked, I just couldn't close the question since I only got comments but I can now with your answer so thanks!

Comment: No worries man happy to help!